# User Can't see Publication in Tridion 2013

Tags: 2013

We have users separated into groups.  Users can't see some publications, though we assigned them some permissions.  What permissions or settings need to be made so that they can see the publication?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Access permission in SDL Tridion is a multi-step process. For your case, you first have a group where you assign all publication visible to the member of this group. Now at this moment if you try to log in to the CMS system with any of the member of this group, you won't be able to see any publication. The second step is that you need to go to the individual publications, right click and go to the security tab. Here choose your group (Check "Show All" if it is not visible) and you will see some thing as shown in the image below:

[image]

For the Group in concern you will see that No Permission has been granted for the user. 
For each publication, you have to specify what all access right the group would have. To make the Publication visible, you must have at least one option enable from the various available shown in the screen shot above.

Comment: The Publication Security tab is specifically *rights*, rather than permissions. +1, but I would note the first step (visibility) is setting `Scope` and the second is for `Rights`. The general idea is authorization and access, but Tridion specifically uses [scope, rights, and permissions](http://www.createandbreak.net/2012/07/sdl-tridion-authorization.html) as separate concepts (each set somewhere else :-)).

Comment: Nice...and perfect categorization. Thanks for sharing Alvin

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking the only right necessary is `Rights.PublicationAccess`, however you can't see it in CME. It will automatically be set by CME when you set any other Right. So you need to set any right, or set `PublicationAccess` through the code.

Also check exceptions. If user is part of multiple groups, in some of them, there might certain permission can be explicitly denied.

Comment: Do you need to do a reboot of the CM before they take affect?  I did add permissions for those users, but they still can't see the publications.

Comment: No reboot needed, should be seen straightaway, see my edit

Comment: +1 to the rights requirement to see a publication. To control which publications users can see, I'd definitely recommend groups, but don't rely on rights alone. If you use the scope setting (available in a user or group's membership in another group), then you can control visible publications in one place, rather than by updating each publication.